# Get OnTouchListener object from View by reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-view, android-reflection

I need modify `onTouch` action on same View. So I needed in field `mOnTouchListener` that stored at `static class ListenerInfo` in `public class View`
I try this:

`Field onTouchListenerField = myView.getClass().getDeclaredField("ListenerInfo.mOnTouchListener");`

and I get error:
`No field ListenerInfo.mOnTouchListener in class MyView; (declaration of 'MyView' appears in ...)`

Why this code they found fields only in `MyView` class, not in base `View`?

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can get that field from `View.class`. but another mistake in your code is you tired to get `ListenerInfo.mOnTouchListener` field but that's not a field. you should first get `mListenerInfo` field from `View.class` and then get `mOnTouchListener` from that.

Try this, works fine.

```java
View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener = null;

try {
    Field mListenerInfoField = View.class.getDeclaredField("mListenerInfo");
    mListenerInfoField.setAccessible(true);
    Object mListenerInfo = mListenerInfoField.get(myView);
    Field mOnTouchListenerField = mListenerInfo.getClass().getDeclaredField("mOnTouchListener");
    mOnTouchListenerField.setAccessible(true);
    mOnTouchListener = (View.OnTouchListener) mOnTouchListenerField.get(mListenerInfo);
    mOnTouchListenerField.setAccessible(false);
    mListenerInfoField.setAccessible(false);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (mOnTouchListener != null) {
    mOnTouchListener.onTouch(myView, null);
}
```